# Arabic Characters in PDF

Tags: java, apache-fop, docx4j

Using Docx4j(3.2.0), tried to generate PDF from docx using 'Docx4J.toFO'.
Arabic characters are missing in PDF.

```
private static void createTestPDF() throws Exception{
  FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("testarabic.docx"));
  WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);

  //Print all available physical fonts
  PhysicalFonts.discoverPhysicalFonts();
  Map<String, PhysicalFont> physicalFonts = PhysicalFonts.getPhysicalFonts();
  Iterator<Entry<String, PhysicalFont>> availableFonts = physicalFonts.entrySet().iterator();
  while(availableFonts.hasNext()) {
     Entry<String, PhysicalFont> font = availableFonts.next();
     String key = font.getKey();
     PhysicalFont pFont = font.getValue();
     System.out.println("Key is " + key + ";; Name " + pFont.getName());
  }

  Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();

  PhysicalFont font  = PhysicalFonts.get("Arial Unicode MS");
  fontMapper.put("Times New Roman", font);

  wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);

  foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);

  OutputStream pdfOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("testarabic.pdf");
  System.out.println(foSettings.getSettings());
  Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, pdfOutputStream, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);

  System.out.println(" Done !!!!");
```

}

[Attached documents](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/arabic-characters-in-pdf-t2167.html).

Environment : Windows 7
Java Version: 1.6
Fop: 1.1
Docx4j: 3.2.0

Kindly assist.

Comment: Which version of FOP is Docx4j using?

Comment: Answered at your crosspost  http://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/arabic-characters-in-pdf-t2167.html